# How to change color of next/previous month arrows (jQuery Datepicker)

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, datepicker, uidatepicker

In jQuery Datepicker I'd like to change the color of the next/previous month arrows on the calendar.

I've seen some tips elsewhere that state that you can just swap out the image entirely

However in my case I would like to keep the 'default' arrow images, but just change its color to a lighter scheme

Is this possible and if so, how?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the UI stylesheet there are `ui-icon` classes which use the `background-image` property to define which icon set is used.  There are a few different sets in the download package, I think mine includes red (#cd0a0a), blue (#2e83ff) as well as white (#ffffff) and a few different shades of grey/back (#222222, #454545 and #888888).  I'm not sure which you're using, but you could either change these, or create a new set of classes which specifically overwrite just the date picker ones, something like...

```
.ui-datepicker-prev .ui-icon, .ui-datepicker-next .ui-icon {
  background-image: url("images/ui-icons_222222_256x240.png");
}
```